# Config file is appearing in bin folder after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a configuration file located in the root folder of my project.  For some reason, whenever I go to publish the project, it creates two instances of this configuration - one in my root folder and one in my bin folder.  Why is this happening and how do I change it so that it doesn't appear in my bin folder?

Comment: Do you have a web application or web site? Also, check the properties window for an option `Copy To Output Directory` and `Build Action`.

Comment: Web Application and the Copy To Output Directory is currently set to Copy Always.  The Build Action is set to Content.  I tried setting the Build Action to None and it simply published it in my bin folder but not my root folder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try making the `Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy` and `Build Action = Content`. Do this only for your config file.

Comment: The web.config is already set to this.  It's not the web.config that is doing this.  It's a separate config file.

Comment: Then what is your separate config file set to?

Comment: I apologize, I'd set the Build Action to None and the Copy to Output Directory to Do not Copy.  Your suggestion seems to have worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks for the answer, you ended my quest very quickly.